# angularjs - scope property not yet available when calling link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, angular-directive-link

I'm writing a directive.

This is the code i'm using:

```
angular.module('weather', []).directive('myWeather', [
  '$ionicSideMenuDelegate', function($ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    var createWeatherConditionLabel, linkFunction;

    createWeatherConditionLabel = function(type) {
      var label;
      label = '';
      debugger;
      switch (type) {
        case 0:
          label = 'Clear';
          break;
        case 1:
          label = 'Clear';
          break;
        case 2:
          label = 'Light Cloud';
          break;
        case 3:
          label = 'Light Cloud';
          break;
        case 5:
          label = 'Windy';
          break;
        case 6:
          label = 'Foggy';
          break;
        case 7:
          label = 'Cloudy';
          break;
        case 15:
          label = 'Rain';
          break;
        case 18:
          label = 'Sleet';
          break;
        case 21:
          label = 'Hail';
          break;
        case 27:
          label = 'Snow';
          break;
        case 30:
          label = 'Showers';
      }
      return label;
    };

    linkFunction = function(scope, el, attr) {
      console.log("scope:", scope);
      scope.showWeatherDetails = false;
      scope.evtClickExpandMenuWeather = function() {
        if (scope.showWeatherDetails === false) {
          return scope.showWeatherDetails = true;
        } else {
          return scope.showWeatherDetails = false;
        }
      };
      scope.$watch((function() {
        return $ionicSideMenuDelegate.isOpenRight();
      }), function(isOpen) {
        if (!isOpen) {
          return scope.showWeatherDetails = false;
        }
      });
      return scope.weatherLabel = createWeatherConditionLabel(scope.weatherType);
    };
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: './directives/tpl.html',
      scope: {
        weatherData: "=",
        weatherType: "="
      },
      link: linkFunction
    };
  }
]);
```

and the directive is called like this:

```
<my-weather weather-data="zones[0].weatherData" weather-type="zones[0].weatherData.weather_type"></my-weather>
```

I need to call a function to create `weatherLabel` and use this in the directive template, but I can't because scope.weatherType is undefined.

How can I wait for scope to be defined before calling the link function?

or, is there a better and efficient (performance wise) way to do this? thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st way: `<my-weather ng-if="zones[0].weatherData.weather_type" ...` so just your directive is not launched untill variable is resolved.
2nd way: use watch on 'weatherType' in directive and update your label.

P.S. your switch is awesome, but better init map i.e.

```
var LABELS = {0 : '...', 1 : '...', ...}
```

and just retrieve label from it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Do you think it's better with the IF or with the watch? which one is more efficient and fast? And yes, maybe you're right. I change it to map, thanks for that as well :)

Comment: I used the IF at the end. Thanks again for the suggesitons

Comment: Actually ng-if uses watch, so it more or less the same - your own watch is a bit more flexible, when ng-if is fast and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the bidirectional binding isolate scope. 
The doc says:

> = or =attr - set up a bidirectional binding between a local scope property and an expression passed via the attribute attr. The
>   expression is evaluated in the context of the parent scope. If no attr
>   name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as
>   the local name.

What is the value of *zones[0].weatherData.weather_type* in your controller? If this property is undefined, *scope.weatherType* in your directive is undefined too.

I wrote an example on plunker. You see how bidirectional binding works.

https://plnkr.co/edit/qK70Z1t1CLI0o5bV7a0Y

script.js

```
var appModule = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.controllerScope = {
      "message": "I am a two ways binding isolate scope"
    };
  }])
  .directive('testDirective', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: "directive-tpl.html",
      replace: true,
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        directiveScope: "="
      },
      link: function(scope) {
        console.log(scope.directiveScope.message);
      }
    }
  });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller='testCtrl'>
    <p>TEST ISOLATE SCOPE</p>
    <p>This is controllerScope:</p>
    <p>{{controllerScope}}</p>
    <test-directive directive-scope='controllerScope'></test-directive>
  </body>

</html>
```

directive-tpl.html

```
<div>
  <p>Hello! I am the template of test-directive</p>
<p>In my scope i have this: </p>
<p>{{directiveScope}}</p>
</div>
```